# How to apply instance on arraylist only once

Tags: java, methods

I'm making a text adventure game, with a method of `Rooms`, that my player can move through. The `Rooms` accept a `RoomInfo` class, which has directions for the other rooms, and an `Event` class, which applies an event to each room. However I want these events to apply only once. Is there a method for doing so?

```
public class RoomDef
{
    private ArrayList<RoomInfo> rooms;

    public void defRooms()
    {
        rooms.add(new RoomInfo(..., new Event(20, 0)));
        rooms.add(new RoomInfo(..., new Event(-30, 0)));
        rooms.add(new RoomInfo(..., new Event(10, 10)));
    }
}
```

Can I perhaps add a boolean that becomes false when the event has been applied?

Here is my constructor for my `RoomInfo` class:

```
RoomInfo(String roomEventText, int roomNumber, Event events) 
{
    this.roomEventText = roomEventText;
    this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
    this.events = events;
}
```

Here is my constructor for my `Event` class:

```
public Event(int life, int damagePoint)
{
    this.life = life; 
    this.damagePoint = damagePoint;
}
```

Could I add a boolean in here?

Comment: Is there any reason you _can't_ just use a boolean flag?

Comment: @mypetlion i was thinking the same thing. But how and where should i place the boolean, in the contructer of my EventClass?

Comment: You could just set the event property of RoomInfo to null as soon as you access it.

Comment: After the thing that you only want to happen once happens.

Comment: I would extend the List class and customize the add method, or simply use a Set or Map.

Comment: @DavidW How what the Syntax for the look, would that be in the RoomInfo class?

Comment: In RoomInfo:
`public Event getEvent() {
     Event result = events;
     events = null;
     return result;
}`

Comment: @DavidW I have a getter and a setter for the event already? Can i use that in my RoomDef class, when i apply the events?

Comment: @kryptering You could probably try these things out in the time it takes you to ask. You know your code better than the people you're asking.

Comment: @DavidW should i apply the getEvent()-method in the RoomDef class?

Comment: Or in the constructer of the Events?

Comment: You apply it when you need to process an Event - when the room is visited.

Comment: I may sound stupid, but how can i do this. I have the constructer for Event where i apply the parameters that goes for each event how can i use the getEvent in RoomDef Class then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by DavidW is probably fine for your use, but long term and more generally it might be better to leave the events property and instead use a boolean. (This would enable for example resetting the rooms without reconstructing them or allowing things like an "undo" move).

Add to RoomInfo

```
private boolean visited = false;
public boolean isVisited() { return visited; }
public void setVisited(boolean visited) { this.visited = visited; }
```

Then when you use RoomInfo, you'll do something like:

```
if (!roomInfo.isVisited()) {
  roomInfo.setVisited(true);
  applyEvents(roomInfo.getEvents());
}
```